# Segmentation Fault on an assembly x64 linux tictactoe

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64, tic-tac-toe

I made an adaptation of a tictactoe from 16 bits msdos to work on linux in 64 bits.

```
section .bss
game_position_pointer resb 9
key resb 1

section .data
new_line db 10
nl_size equ $-new_line

game_draw db "_|_|_", 10 
          db "_|_|_", 10
          db "_|_|_", 10, 0
gd_size equ $-game_draw

win_flag db 0

player db "0", 0
p_size equ $-player

game_over_message db "FIM DE JOGO AMIGOS", 10, 0
gom_size equ $-game_over_message

game_start_message db "JOGO DA VELHA"
gsm_size equ $-game_start_message

player_message db "JOGADOR ", 0
pm_size equ $-player_message

win_message db " GANHOU!", 0
wm_size equ $-win_message

type_message db "ENTRE COM UMA POSICAO NO TABULEIRO: ", 0
tm_size equ $-type_message

clear_screen_ASCII_escape db 27,"[H",27,"[2J"      ; <ESC> [H  <ESC>  [2J
cs_size equ $-clear_screen_ASCII_escape

section .text 
global _start 

_start:
call set_game_pos_pointer

main_loop:
call clear_screen

mov rsi, game_start_message
mov rdx, gsm_size
call print

mov rsi, new_line
mov rdx, nl_size
call print

mov rsi, player_message
mov rdx, pm_size
call print

mov rsi, player
mov rdx, p_size
call print

mov rsi, new_line
mov rdx, nl_size
call print

mov rsi, game_draw
mov rdx, gd_size
call print

mov rsi, new_line
mov rdx, nl_size
call print

mov rsi, type_message
mov rdx, tm_size
call print

call read_keyboard               ; Vamos ler a posição que o usuário vai passar

mov al, [key]
sub al, 49                       ; 49 equivale a "1" em ASCII, eu faço essa subtração porque eu quero converter ASCII para inteiro, ao mesmo tempo que faço subtraio de 1 o valor inteiro


call update_draw

call check

cmp byte[win_flag], 1
je game_over

call change_player

jmp main_loop

change_player:

mov rsi, player
xor byte[rsi], 1  ; Tipo um xor swap :)

ret

print:
mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
syscall
ret

read_keyboard:
mov rax, 0
mov rdi, 0
mov rsi, key 
mov rdx, 1
syscall

ret

clear_screen:
mov rsi, clear_screen_ASCII_escape
mov rdx, cs_size
call print
ret

set_game_pos_pointer:
mov rsi, game_draw
mov rbx, game_position_pointer

mov rcx, 9

loop_1:
    mov [rbx], rsi
    add rsi, 2

    inc rbx
    loop loop_1

ret

update_draw:
lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rax]

mov rsi, player

cmp byte[rsi], "0"
je draw_x

cmp byte[rsi], "1"
je draw_o

draw_x:
    mov cl, "x"
    jmp update

draw_o:
    mov cl, "o"
    jmp update

update:

    mov [rbx], cl


ret

check:
call check_line
ret

check_line:

mov rcx, 0

check_line_loop:
    cmp rcx, 0
    je first_line

    cmp rcx, 1
    je second_line

    cmp rcx, 2
    je third_line

    call check_column
    ret

    first_line:
        mov rsi, 0
        jmp do_check_line

    second_line:
        mov rsi, 3
        jmp do_check_line

    third_line:
        mov rsi, 6
        jmp do_check_line

    do_check_line:
        inc rcx

        lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]
        mov al, [rbx]
        cmp al, "_"
        je check_line_loop

        inc rsi
        lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]
        cmp al, [rbx]
        jne check_line_loop

        inc rsi
        lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]
        cmp al, [rbx]
        jne check_line_loop

    mov byte[win_flag], 1
    ret

check_column:
mov rcx, 0

check_colum_loop:
    cmp rcx, 0
    je first_column

    cmp rcx, 1
    je second_column

    cmp rcx, 2
    je third_column

    call check_diagonal
    ret

    first_column:
        mov rsi, 0
        jmp do_check_column

    second_column:
        mov rsi, 1
        jmp do_check_column

    third_column:
        mov rsi, 2
        jmp do_check_column

    do_check_column:
        inc rcx

        lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]
        mov al, [rbx]
        cmp al, "_"
        je check_colum_loop

        add rsi, 3
        lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]
        cmp al, [rbx]
        jne check_colum_loop

        add rsi, 3
        lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]
        cmp al, [rbx]
        jne check_colum_loop

        mov byte[win_flag], 1
        ret

check_diagonal:
mov rcx, 0

check_diagonal_loop:
    cmp rcx, 0
    je first_diagonal

    cmp rcx, 1
    je second_diagonal

    ret

first_diagonal:
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rdx, 4          ; tamanho do pulo que vamos dar para o meio da diagonal 
    jmp do_check_diagonal

second_diagonal:
    mov rsi, 2
    mov rdx, 2
    jmp do_check_diagonal

do_check_diagonal:
    inc rcx

    lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]
    mov al, [rbx]
    cmp al, "_"
    je check_diagonal_loop

    add rsi, rdx
    lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]
    cmp al, [rbx]
    jne check_diagonal_loop

    add rsi, rdx
    lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]
    cmp al, [rbx]
    jne check_diagonal_loop

mov byte[win_flag], 1
ret

game_over:
call clear_screen

mov rsi, game_start_message
mov rdx, gsm_size
call print

mov rsi, new_line
mov rdx, nl_size
call print

mov rsi, game_draw
mov rdx, gd_size
call print

mov rsi, new_line
mov rdx, nl_size
call print

mov rsi, game_over_message
mov rdx, gom_size
call print

mov rsi, player_message
mov rdx, pm_size
call print

mov rsi, player
mov rdx, p_size
call print

mov rsi, win_message
mov rdx, wm_size
call print

jmp fim

fim:
mov rax, 60
mov rdi, 0
syscall
```

But there's a segmentation fault in this line from label update_draw:

```
mov [rbx], cl
```

I just can't comprehend what i am doing wrong. Any suggestions or help will be appreciated

EDIT: 
I have edited the code adding the sugestions and, strangely, I've found out that the change_player label isn't changing anything, in fact it looks like that my entire code isn't managing to modify the variables of section data. For example,

```
change_player:
    mov si, player
    xor byte[si], 1  ; Tipo um xor swap :)
    ret
```

isn't changing the variable player, the value is always "0"

Comment: Which instruction is the segfault on?  Use `gdb` to find out.  This is a massive code dump with barely any comments, the opposite of a [mcve].  http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/

Comment: Oh, there was text after the code, which I only saw after fixing your formatting.  What value is in `rbx` at that point (check with a debugger.  `mov bl, byte[game_position_pointer + rax]` writes the low byte of RBX, so that looks suspicious unless something else sets RBX to a valid pointer before reaching the instruction that uses it as a pointer, or if you're indexing into something that's 256-byte aligned and partial-register writes are a hacky way to do array indexing.

Comment: `mov si, [player]` is a load that replaces the previous value in `si`.  Did you mean to store with `mov [player], si`?  x86-64 has lots of registers; you probably don't need memory for that at all, e.g. `xor r15d, 1`.  Use a debugger to single-step and examine registers next time you get stuck.

Comment: actually I forgot to edit this last part, look at it now.

Comment: the xor is working as it should do, nothing I write in these variables are in fact being wrote. Another example is the update_draw label, the line mov [rbx], cl seems to have none effect.

Comment: `mov si, player`: pointers don't fit in 16 bits, so this truncates the pointer.  `xor byte[si], 1` doesn't even assemble; x86-64 doesn't support 16-bit address-size.  I call bullshit.  Post your real code.  NASM says `error: impossible combination of address sizes` when trying to assemble that instruction with `nasm -felf64 foo.asm`.  **Use a debugger** to examine registers / memory as you single-step.

Comment: I'll learn how to use gdb first. But btw, thx for the replies and patiente.

Comment: But, as I said, I actually forgot to edit this line. The code running here is: mov rsi, player xor byte[rsi], 1

Comment: The code in your question is still not updated.  Always copy/paste instead of re-typing, especially if you're a beginner so you might not notice differences like SI instead of RSI.  It's just a waste of everyone's time.  But yeah, use GDB or a front-end like https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui/ to debug.  Otherwise you have no idea what's wrong in a medium-to-large program like this.

Comment: I'm sorry for all of this embarassment, i've already updated the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

A few bits look suspicious, particularly

```
mov bl, byte[game_position_pointer + rax]
```

and

```
mov rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]
mov al, [rbx]
```

bl overlays the lowest 8 bits of rbx, so that operation appears like it is moving the byte from the board location in ‘rax’ into bl.   Rbx is subsequently used as a pointer (ie. your faulting instruction).

In the second example, it looks like the intent is to load the address of the board position into rbx, then get the value at that location.   That would look something like

```
lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]
mov al, [rbx]
```

or the more succinct

```
mov al, game_position_pointer[rsi]
```

apologies if I messed up the syntax, your flavour of assembler isn’t familiar to me.  GNU provides one with a much more precise syntax.

Comment: again, masm syntax is a mess, but you seem to be using player as a pointer rather than a label.   I am surprised you aren’t getting many segvs.

Comment: when I say a mess, the nice thing about the ‘rough’ syntax of gas is that you explicitly differentiate between loading the addresses and values; whereas the DOS asm obscures this.

Comment: I tested here and I discovered that the sys_read is reading the "\n" after I type the position, so it skips the next cycle of loop and go back to "0", making the impression player variable never changed. Haha.

Comment: Nevetheless, the problem still remains, in the game_position_pointer, the function set_game_pos_pointer were supposed to associate each square of the board with a position, when the update_draw is called, the pointer works well, but the string game_draw is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

in :

```
mov rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]

mov al,[rbx]
```

you use the value in location `[game_position_pointer + rsi]` as pinter that leads to segmentation error you need use `game_position_pointer + rsi` location itself

**I don't know if it works in your game case or  you can just use

```
mov al ,byte[game_position_pointer + rsi]
```

Comment: I have edited the code with some changes, like lea rbx, [game_position_pointer + rsi]

Comment: Thx for the reply!

Comment: The content of the array game_position_pointer is 9 addresses, that's why I use the value in location [game_position_pointer + rsi] as a pointer. But leads to seg f. I don't know how i can dereference the address.